# How can I compute the silhouette score of a clustering using a custom distance metric?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I'm working with network analysis and I performed spectral clustering in a graph and I'd like to evaluate my clustering using silhouette score, but I'm getting an error which makes me question if I'm going in the right direction.

Here is a small reproducible example of the problem I'm facing:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score


def compute_node_distance(nodeA, nodeB):  
  return (len(nodeA['ID'])-len(nodeB['ID'])) * random.random()

df_test = pd.DataFrame(
                       [('00A5097258', 4),
                        ('0F05109', 5),
                        ('030714318X', 4),
                        ('0B05117', 2),
                        ('134188', 1),
                        ('0J019281', 3)], 
                        columns=['ID', 'cluster']
                       )
silhouette_score(
                 df_test, 
                 df_test['cluster'],
                 metric=lambda a,b: compute_node_distance(a,b)
                )
```

In order to my custom function to work, I only need the nodes' IDs, so I believe this should be enough.

However, when running this code, `silhouette_score` gives me an error, saying that it couldn't convert one my nodes ID to float:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '00A5097258'
```

The thing is I do NOT want this value to be converted to a float, because I have my own metric function that is perfectly able to compute the distance between two nodes given their IDs as strings.

I know I could pre-compute the distance matrix between my nodes and use `metric='precomputed'`, but my actual dataframe is really big (65000+ rows) and storing such a matrix is really inefficient, so I'm trying to compute the distances as they are needed.
Can someone please help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong and why silhouette_score is trying to convert my IDs to floats?
Thanks.

Comment: A [reprex] may help

Comment: Thanks @SergeyBushmanov. I've updated the question to include such an example. I hope it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: Check out docs for [silhouette_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html). You have 2 problems: df_test must be a numerical matrix (n_samples, n_features), `metrics` is a callable returning distance between 2 points. As soon as you correct those I believe you're fine to go.

Comment: Thank you @SergeyBushmanov. I was suspecting that the fact df_test wasn't numeric might be the problem, however, it didn't make much sense to me. If I'm assuming the responsibility to define the metric myself and I'm able to calculate the distance using strings, then why won't it allow me? I think I'll just associate a unique number to each row and use a dict to retrieve the original string from inside the compute_node_distance function.

Comment: silhouette_score, as all the classes and methods in sklearn, is coded in a certain way (you may wish to have a look at [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/metrics/cluster/_unsupervised.py#L38) ) thus expecting inputs to conform to certain rules (see my comment above). If you're not satisfied with that you're free to recode your own silhoutte score

Comment: Thank you, I think the workaround I thought of will work fine. I believe you may want to actually answer the question and I'll mark it as the correct answer. Thank you a lot!